# What is the right form of answer for the question "Where?"

Tags: склонение

в Хельсинк**и**

**OR**

в Хельсинк**ах**?

Comment: Second examle sounds like a name of a one of Moscow suborbs.

Answer (score 7):

According to paragraph 184 (non-declining nouns) of the Short Russian Grammar ([direct link - in Russian](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5312&0a0=1712#184)), foreign-language toponyms that end in vowels other than *-а* and *-ы* do not decline.

Hence, you'll get:

> Где?
>   В Хельсинки

but

> Где?
>   В Каннах

You do often hear *в Хельсинках*, however this usage is colloquial and is not grammatically correct.  This is just an analogue of the declension of Russian toponyms with similar ending.  Compare the above with:

> Где?
>   В Лужниках

Comment: Whoever downvoted, an explanation would be nice

Answer (score 6):

Toponyms which calque plural from the language of origin do decline as plurals in Russian: *в Афинах / Кумах / Каннах / Сиракузах*, just the same as native Russian toponyms in plural: в *Мытищах / Химках / Чебоксарах*

However, *Хельсинки* is not plural in Finnish and hence not plural in Russian.

So it's a singular noun, and as any singular Russian noun ending in *-и*, is not declinable.

Correct form would be *в Хельсинки*.